# Under what conditions $\sigma(X)=\sigma(Y \circ X)$

Tags: measure-theory

$X:(\mathbb R^{d_1}, \mathcal B^{d_1}) \to (\mathbb R^{d_2}, \mathcal B^{d_2}), Y:(\mathbb R^{d_2}, \mathcal B^{d_2}) \to (\mathbb R^{d_3}, \mathcal B^{d_3}), d_i \in \mathbb N $

What should I require from $Y$ in terms of "manageable" functional properties (e.g. Y is bijective, continuous) to guarantee that $\sigma(X)=\sigma(Y \circ X)$.

I clearly need to make sure that $Y^{-1}(\mathcal B^{d_3}) = \mathcal B^{d_2}$.

Comment: I think you want something like "$Y$ is Borel measurable, and injective on the range of $X$".

Comment: @NateEldredge: Does that really suffice? IIRC then (surprisingly), injective Borel functions are automatically invertible with Borel measirable inverse if they are injective on a Borel measurable set. But do we know that the range of $X $ is Borel?

Comment: @PhoemueX: Good point.  Maybe we should say "injective on a Borel set containing the range of $X$."